# How to locate “memo” folder on samsung galaxy j5

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-j5, s-memo

I had taken backup on "phone" and "card" folder in my laptop before giving service to the service center.

Now, the phone has been fully formatted and it is as new. Now there is no "memo" in my phone.

So, I want to restore the memo from the backed up folders. But I can't able to locate the "memo" folder. Can someone guide me. Thanks.

Comment: How did you take the backup? Did you copy folders/files, did you use an app or did you use a program on your computer?

Comment: I had copied through data cable.

Comment: In that case it is quite likely that you have not backed up the necessary data. Each app stores data in a location that is not accessible when connecting your device to a computer. Unfortunately I expect you have lost the memos you are after.